# How to change a View size while animating in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view, drawable

I have the following set up inside a fragment in android studio:
[image]

This animates from 100% to a received value.

The circle is a ProgressBarHorizontal with this drawable:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:useLevel="true"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="8sp" >
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

And the text, a TextView.

Both Views are animated in this function:

```java
public void capacityRecieved(int value){

        valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(100,value);
        animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt (progressBar, "progress", 500, value*500/100);
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                String displayText = valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString() + "%";
                capacityTextView.setText(displayText);
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.setDuration(5000);
        animation.setDuration(5000); //in milliseconds
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.start();
        animation.start();
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

When I rotate the device, I adjust the sizes with the following lines:

```java
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    final int pHeight = progressBar.getHeight();
    ViewTreeObserver observer = rootView.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = progressBar.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = progressBar.getHeight();
            int newHeight = progressBar.getHeight();
            float newSize = ((float)newHeight/(float)pHeight)*70;
            progressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
            capacityTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, newSize);
            rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

This works great, except if I rotate the device **while animating**, in such case, the new configuration isn't applied (I have to re-rotate the phone and then it works well)

How can I change the sizes while animating?